# How to stop subprocess in Django management command?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a Python program that I want to run as a subprocess which should be invoked by a Django custom management command. It is a long-running program which I have to stop manually. It is easy to start the subprocess but how to stop it?

Here is a theoretical example of what I'm thinking about:

```
import subprocess
from optparse import make_option
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand    

class Command(BaseCommand):

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--start',
            action='store_true',
            dest='status'
        ),
        make_option('--stop',
            action='store_false',
            dest='status',
            default=False
        )
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        status = options.get('status')

        # If the command is executed with status=True it should start the subprocess
        if status:
            p = subprocess.Popen(...)
        else:
            # if the command is executed again with status=False, 
            # the process should be terminated.
            # PROBLEM: The variable p is not known anymore. 
            # How to stop the process?
            p.terminate() # This probably does not work
```

Is that possible what I'm thinking about? If not, can you come up with some other possibilities of how to handle this behavior? I definitely would like to start and stop the same subprocess using the same management command using optparse options. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `p` variable does indeed not exist in your context of `status == False`.
You could use a [`pidfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain) where you write down `p`'s `pid` when the command is ran with `status == True` and kill (`os.kill` would work well) the process whose `pid` is in that `pidfile` when you run the command is ran with `status == False`.

You probably make the whole thing a bit simpler by just writing down the `pid` of the Python script that's running the subprocess command in the first place and kill that one.

That's not very graceful however.

Comment: Ah, your first option sounds like a good idea. Is there a Python module to write such a pidfile automatically or do I simply take `Popen.pid` and manually write that to a file?

Comment: @PeterStahl Just write it to a file, you're basically just doing: `with open('proc.pid', 'w') as pidfile: pidfile.write(p.pid)`

Comment: Alright, good to know. I'm going to try this now and if it works I will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thank you! :)