# Is there a way to reliably list subprocesses in Go?

Tags: process, go, exec, portability

My program is using `exec.Command` to run a child process (that I don't control), which is in turn kicking off another child process.  The problem is that the second child process is not running under the first child process, but instead the original process, leaving me no way to explicitly kill it if I need to.  And I do need to.

So, is there a platform-agnostic way to list subprocesses, so that I can explicitly clean it up?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really Go specific. Maybe tagging it with some thing more general would help it get seen.

Comment: @Logiraptor I added some tags, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No, you can't in a cross platform way. (Is this on windows, because it can't happen on Linux/Unix)

Answer (score 0):

The platform agnostic way would be to use [PID files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain), or some other similar mechanism. The downside is that you have to get the subprocess applications (and their vendors) to produce the necessary information.

The only other possibility is developing your own multi-platform library, as the subprocess semantics and the process related APIs change from platform to platform. The a few utilities that exist simply get a list of all processes in the system, and query for each one's parent pid, and build a tree using custom logic.