# Determining the PID of a batch job in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I submitted a set(~20 jobs) of processes (mpirun -n 16 executable) through a bash script (say ./run.sh &) which takes a few days to complete. After submission, I exited the terminal. Now when I log back in and top, I can only see the PID of the current process. How can I determine the PID of the run.sh so that I can kill run.sh that will terminate the batch jobs instead of killing each of those 20 jobs individually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After each command execute the following:

```
LAST_CMD_PID=$!
```

This variable will hold the PID of the last executed command.

A common practice is saving the pid in a file with suffix ".pid" for later usage (for more info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain)).

In order to kill run.sh you could get its PID with $! and kill it. BUT killing run.sh will also kill all the commands that run.sh triggered because they were forked from it (i.e. they are its children) (see [this post](http://When%20the%20shell%20closes,%20it%20sends%20SIGHUP%20to%20all%20processes%20in%20its%20process%20group.%20nohup%20tells%20the%20command%20to%20ignore%20SIGHUP.) for more info). In order the children to remain alive they should become daemons, i.e. to not have a parent process. In order to do this check they should be executed with the command nohup:

```
nohup your_cmd_here &
```

Comment: thanks but when I have executed some other commands and exited the session, I don't think "$!" would store anything there. Is that case how do I get the PID?

Comment: If you have exited the session then run.sh dies and therefore is it doesn't have a PID! But if you put it in the background then $! will return its PID. Keep in mind that all the commands that you execute in a shell are forked from the shell and therefore they are children of the shell (except of 'course if you use the nohup command as I have already mentioned).