# How to get old process id after system restarts in windows OS?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project In which I need to get the old PID of a process back in Windows OS.

Old PID means the PID which was given to a particular process (for example Notepad was given PID 100) before system restarts. Now after restarting system, I need the older PID(100)  AND start that process again.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
```

Here's my example code ，please provide solution if possible or any other way I can get the old PID back and old process back.

Comment: Unless windows records these things in its event/security logs or you log them as you start your application or before you restart your computer, I dont think it's possible.

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: Finding the ID **before** the system restarts and writing it to a file which then gets read **after** the system restarts is already part of what you plan to do, isn't it?

Comment: Please explain more about the role of each of the three tagged languages.

Comment: You can restart the process just as you mentioned within your example code

Comment: Why do you need to get back the old PID after system restart? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Please don't spam tags, this is clearly just Java

Comment: Because I want restart the application like notepad in which user works before system restart.

Comment: Another thing - you wont be able to nominate a PID prior to a process starting.  The OS will allocate the PID at the time - you cannot tell the OS to start an application and to use a specified PID.

Comment: @PatelVikash just restart the application like in your code snippet, what's wrong with that? Why do you care about the PID?

Comment: @Michael Walz Because I am working on a project Ram-Reloader  that enables you to reboot Windows without losing your place in your work. It builds a checklist of currently open applications, and will restart the apps you've selected the next time you logon to the computer.

Comment: @Michael Walz please suggest any other way to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

On unix systems, it is common practise to create a simple text file named `.pid` in the same directory as the scripts to start and stop the application. It contains the `pid` number of the running process.

If the application crashes (or the system restarts without closing it down cleanly), the `.pid` file will remain.

When restarting an application, although the pid number contained in the `.pid` file is no longer relevant from an operational perspective, it can be handy to know that the process crashed (or at least didnt shut down cleanly) - usually the `start` script for the operation will check for a `.pid` file and not start the application until this file is removed manually.

So you could do something similar in your case. You would need to "wrap" the process / service startup and shutdown to facilitate this.

Here's a question about that: [What is a .pid file and what does it contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain)

Answer (score 0):

You should store a list of open applications (names/exe paths), not their PIDs, as the old PIDs will be meaningless after the process has terminated/aborted. Upon restarting the application, a new PID will be assigned by the OS, which you as a programmer will have no control over.