# Limiting number of concurrent instances of Tcl application and querying the number of connections to a database file?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

These two question are in the context of a single desktop machine running a Tcl application connecting to locally stored SQLite databases and involving no external connections to them.

1. Is it possible to limit the operating system to opening one instance of a Tcl application at any one time? (I have not yet done so but plan to put it in a star kit.) Tcl is acting as a local server and I suppose I could use a hard-coded port such that a second instance would not be able to open another server on the same port; but I've been asking Tcl to open a random unused port to avoid the same conflict with other applications that may be running.
2. If two instances of a Tcl application are opened concurrently, is there a way to "know" in one instance that another instance has already opened a connnection to a specific SQLite database file? Alternatively, can a SQLite database be queried to count connections regardless of which applications "own" the connections?

The reason for asking is that I'm trying to make it very difficult for a user to accidentally edit their own content from two locations and end up ruining or losing it. I'm using a browser as the UI and, although that causes complications, it appears that it can be managed in Tcl as long as there is only one instance of the Tcl application running.

If I try to track the state in the database, the issue seems to be that the user can always find a way to close the browser UI (even in application mode and maybe kiosk mode) leaving no reliable way of informing Tcl to change that state in the database.

Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

Comment: Why not check if the database is locked see https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html and only if not lock it, so that other instances will stop if locked

Comment: 1) Consider solving this with [database transactions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-transactions/) and only commit when the edit is complete. 2) Executables can use a lock file to know if it's running. When the executable starts it tries to exclusively lock the file. If it can't because it's already locked it exits. [Add the process ID to the file for more features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain#8296204).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting the number of running instances is fairly awkward, especially in the context of both containers and multi-user systems. The key problem is that while you could write the current application instance identity to a file somewhere (which might be a DB), you cannot be sure that the information currently in the file is accurate; crashes can happen (including hardware crashes). I suppose you might be able to use [dbus](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/dbus%2Dtcl) to discover the live process; the dbus session would have the right sort of scope. (An equivalent must exist on other platforms; it's just too useful.)

A program like `lsof` can tell you what files a process has open. If you tell it to list a specific process that you are running (i.e., that isn't running for another user) then it is reasonably fast. You can also get a lot of information out of `/proc` directly.

That said, I'd structure things to allow concurrent access and completely ignore my preceding two paragraphs. Keep transactions short but coherent (that's the point!) and you will get reasonable performance. You don't have to use a single transaction per `INSERT`; if you need to make multiple changes at once to get overall coherence, you *should* do so, and do it with an explicit transaction. Just don't do long processing in a transaction.